# Compression option disabled on new sprites

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on a project in which I need to disable compression on sprites.

Yesterday I had to reinstall OSX and Unity, and now any new sprites that I create have the compression option greyed out.

[image]

The problem appears to be fixed by manually editing the new sprite's .meta file and changing textureCompression to 0.

[image]

I guess this is a newer version of the editor and there's an option somewhere. Could someone give me a pointer please? Thank you :-)

EDIT: Full import settings:

[image]

Comment: I'm currently using 5.5.0f3. Can't confirm which version I was using previously, but it was installed approx 2 weeks ago. The sprite is used as an in-game sprite. Post updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in *iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad settings* mode.Select the Texture, switch to *Default* mode then you can disable compression.

[image]

Comment: Oh my god I feel so stupid!  Thank you so much for your help.  I'd tried clicking on the PC / iOS icons on the right, but totally forgot that you can click on Default.  Much appreciated :-)